# Arming A Brushless Motor Controller Connected to ESP8266

Tags: arduino, brushless-dc-motor, esp8266, motor-controller, lipo

I am trying to control a brushless motor with WeMOS D1 ESP8266

The motor controller and motor specs are below:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/114619313561

A 11.1v LiPo battery powers both the controller and ESP8266 (VIN, GND, D9)

The motor controller user manual is here:
[image: user manual]

The wiring photo is here
[image: wiring photo]

Turning on the controller spins its fan. but the motor does not spin.
What is the arming procedure to get the beeps to get the motor started?

Have I chosen wrong hardware to work with a circuit board?

Here' some code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo ESC1;

int pos = 0; //Sets position variable

void arm(){
  setSpeed(0); //Sets speed variable
  delay(1000);
  setSpeed(90); //Sets speed variable
  delay(1000);
  setSpeed(135); //Sets speed variable
  delay(1000);
  setSpeed(0); //Sets speed variable
  delay(1000);
}

void setSpeed(int speed){
  int angle = map(speed, 0, 100, 0, 180); //Sets servo positions to different speeds
  ESC1.write(speed); //angle
}

void setup() {
  ESC1.attach(2); //Adds ESC to certain pin.  GPIO2 is pin 9
  arm();
}

void loop() {

  int speed; //Implements speed variable

  for(speed = 0; speed <= 70; speed += 5) { //Cycles speed up to 70% power for 1 second
    setSpeed(speed); //Creates variable for speed to be used in in for loop
    delay(1000);
  }

  delay(4000); //Stays on for 4 seconds
 
  for(speed = 70; speed > 0; speed -= 5) { // Cycles speed down to 0% power for 1 second
      setSpeed(speed); delay(1000);
  }

  setSpeed(0); //Sets speed variable to zero no matter what
  delay(1000); //Turns off for 1 second

}
```

Comment: Do you also realize the RC convention is a pulse width between 1ms and 2ms long? Not 0%-100%?

Comment: Please don't shout.

Comment: Thanks @DKNguyen. I am not as knowledgeable. your guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Found something here ... what PWM should be done and in what series to arm the motor? https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-pwm-arduino-ide/

Comment: What's the thing on top of the motor?

Comment: a wheel @BruceAbbott

Comment: It's a bit confusing because your motor looks different to the one in the eBay listing, but please bear in mind that with a Kv of 4370rpm/V it will try to spin at over 50,000rpm at full throttle. I hope your wheel isn't attached to the motor shaft...

Comment: Good observation @Bruce Abbott. Image in the ebay listing had changed.

Answer (score 2):

The "PWM" used in equipment for radio controlled models , is not actually true PWM where pulses are sent at a fixed frequency with an on-time proportional to the off-time betweeh 0% and 100%.

The "PWM" used in RC is actually a a pulse that varies between 1-2ms in width. So for 0%-100% it would be 1-2ms. But if it's -100%-100% then it would still be 1-2ms, except that 1.5ms would be considered 0%. It's not reading the ratio between on time and off time. It is literally measuring how long each pulse is high remains.

The pulse frequency can be pretty sloppy too. It just has to be sent often enough so that analog equipment power pulses frequently enough to hold position (like an analog servo) or frequently enough so the digital equipment (like an ESC or digital servo) does not think the radio signal has been lost.

Comment: Yes to all the above, but note that there's usually an "arming" procedure involving reducing the pulse width to minimum (1ms or down to 0.5 ms) for a second or so, then increasing it to start the motor. This avoids accidental power-ons at full speed. Details *should* be in the datasheet...